# Twilio SIP: Making Outbound Calls

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have successfully set up a Cisco VOIP phone to register with Twilio via SIP

I have created a SIP domain, authenticated, and the phone is registered

I have set up a TwiML Bin that looks like:

```
<Response>
   <Dial callerId="+44203XXXXXXX">
          {{To}}
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

But I get an error:

> Dial: Invalid phone number.
>   The area code or local exchange code of the phone number does not appear to be valid

And in the error the Request Body looks like:

```
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="+44203XXXXXXX">
          sip:0170XXXXXXX@DOMAIN.sip.us1.twilio.com
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

However I think that the Request Body should look like:

```
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="+44203XXXXXXX">
          +44170XXXXXXX
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

How can I change the TwiML to dial just the phone number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As you've discovered, the `To` parameter that a SIP phone delivers to the Twilio endpoint is not a phone number but a SIP address with a phone number embedded within.

TwiML Bins aren't currently smart enough to extract that phone number using the templating functions. So, to do this you will need to host a small application that can rewrite the `To` parameter into a phone number.

We have an example application, written in Python and deployable to Heroku (or wherever you want really), that does this already for you. Check out the [code here](https://github.com/timbeyers/sip2pstn-simpledial) and read about [how to use it here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/10/introducing-sip-registration.html).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for your help! However that seems to be a bit of a fail on Twilio's part.  Surely you should be able to Trim the phone number out of the 'To' field, or there should be an option to do that automatically.  There must be others with a similar issue, are we able to find out if a fix is on their roadmap?  I'll give the heroku fix a try...

Comment: TwiML Bins were set up, initially by a third party and then purchased by Twilio, before we even started doing SIP registration. So this feature was not considered. I can't speak to whether TwiML Bins will provide this functionality in the future, however we have provided a server implementation that will do this for you, so hopefully that does work.

Comment: Wow, that WAS easy.  Thank you for your help, your heroku magic worked a-ok

Comment: Update: AFAIK you can now add in a <sip> within the <dial> and this will handle calling to sip. See https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sip

Comment: That's correct, but this question is about making an outgoing call from a SIP phone to a regular phone number. If you were looking for details on calling to SIP addresses, then I'm glad you found it :)

Answer (score 1):

To dial SIP numbers you need to tell it that it's SIP.

Use the following instead, adding in `<sip>` between `<dial>` and the sip address:

```
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="+44203XXXXXXX">
       <Sip>
          sip:0170XXXXXXX@DOMAIN.sip.us1.twilio.com
       </Sip>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

More info at [TWIML™ VOICE:  Documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sip)